# Sending data from web app to MAUI android app on same device without a server

Tags: android, .net, maui

is it possible to send text data from web app to MAUI android app without a server?
Both are running on same device.
I didn't find any documentation about that on the internet.

How to do that?

I tried Push notification using firebase, but I prefer to do that locally.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to share data between two apps on the same device?

Comment: Between web app and android app on the same device

Comment: by "web app", do you mean Chrome or some other browser running a web app?

Comment: Web app that run on chrome brower

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+share+data+between+browser+and+app+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Without using a server. They are running on the same device so using a server is unnecessary

Comment: See the link above.  There are numerous existing questions on this topic.